# Comparing populations of greatly different size

Tags: population

I'm reading an analysis someone gave me comparing two different populations of loans.  One has about 3,000,000 loans and the other has about 6,000.  The analysis compares the percentage of defaults in the two populations but says nothing about the different population sizes.  Does that affect the validity/reliability of the percentages?

CLARIFICATION: one commenter asked if these were samples or whole populations - it is the latter, the default rates are based on the whole population, not a sample.

Comment: I find it hard to believe any (credible) analysis says nothing about the two populations. I would expect to see CIs that are unbelievably tight in group 1, and a bit wider in group 2.